# SwelteKit - Form enhance - update fields from result

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sveltekit

I am trying to update fields in form after validation. After submit I am checking if password match and if not clear field. Without enhance I dont have issue but I am unable to figure out how to make it works with enhance.

Currenty I have this.

+page.svelte

```
       ...
        <!-- Form -->
        <form
            method="post"
            action="?/register"
            class="flex flex-col gap-6 m-2"
            use:enhance={({formData}) => {
                return async ({ result, update }) => {
                    if (result.type === 'success') {
                        // Redirect to login
                        window.location.href = './login';
                    }

                    console.log(result);
                    applyAction(result);
                    update();
                };
            }}
            ...
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-evenly gap-6">
                <h1 class="font-bold mr-auto text-2xl">Password</h1>
                <input name="password" required type="password" placeholder="Password" value={form?.data.password ?? ''} class="w-60 rounded-lg p-2 border-2 'border-gray-300 focus:border-orange-500 focus:outline-none" />
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-evenly gap-6">
                <p class="font-bold mr-auto text-2xl">Password confirm</p>
                <input name="passwordConfirm" required type="password" placeholder="Password confirm" value={form?.data.passwordConfirm ?? ''} class="w-60 rounded-lg p-2 border-2 'border-gray-300' focus:border-orange-500 focus:outline-none" />
            </div>
            ...
```

+page.server.ts

```
        ...
        // Check if password and passwordConfirm match
        if (input.password !== input.passwordConfirm) {
            input.password = '';
            input.passwordConfirm = '';
            return fail(422, { error: 'Passwords do not match', data: input });
        }
        ...
```

Comment: Why not throw a `redirect` directly in the action?

Comment: Noted, I didn't get that far. I was just trying some stuff. I want to use enhance function only for pre submit validation and update.